# Adding binding to a custom control on windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have created a custom image button for a project. This is based on the code provided at https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Custom-Image-Button-in-4b300b62.

I've adjusted the image button to suit my needs and it looks fine in the designer. However, I'm trying to bind the textblocks to a view model using a DependencyProperty.

The guts of the button looks like this

```
<StackPanel x:Name="Panel" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Image Margin="10,0,-10,0" x:Name="Image" Width="48" Height="48" Source="/Assets/Images/mappin.png"/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Width="400" x:Name="txtHeading" Text="Mooo" Grid.Row="0" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0,-10,0" FontFamily="/TfL.CongestionCharge.WindowsPhone;component/Assets/Fonts/NJFont-Book.ttf#NJFont Book" />
            </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Nothing amazing, but does what I need.

The code behind for the TextBlock dependency looks like this

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextDependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
   "Text",
   typeof(string),
   typeof(UserControl),
   new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValue(TextDependencyProperty) as string;
        }

        set
        {
            SetValue(TextDependencyProperty, txtHeading.GetType().GetProperty("System.String").GetValue(txtHeading, null));
        }
    }
```

(I was getting could not convert from a System.Windows.Bindable to System.String error originally, this code will compile but gives a null ref. exception in the setter)

Am I going about this the correct way and do I need to create a DependencyProperty if I try to bind to an ICommand or can I just use

```
private ICommand command;
public ICommand Command
    {
        get
        {
            return command;
        }

        set
        {
            command = value;
            command.Execute(value);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your setter to be "normal" one, instead:

```
SetValue(TextDependencyProperty, txtHeading.GetType().GetProperty("System.String").GetValue(txtHeading, null));
```

Use this:

```
SetValue(TextDependencyProperty, value);
```

Give your `UserControl` a name:

```
<UserControl ... x:Name="thisControl">
```

In your `TextBlock` use a binding to your control property:

```
Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=thisControl}"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It does. Only two issues now - the image doesn't show and the bound text is not showing either :(

Comment: That's odd. This change should have no impact on image. Can you provide a full XAML of your `UserControl`?

Comment: D'oh missing / before Assets. Not sure about the text not binding though :(

Comment: In code provided, you have no dependency properties in your control. Also you have no binding defined from your properties to the text block and image.

Comment: Line 81 and 87 has the properties. The bindings come from the master view model (such as Binding VrmLookupCommand)

Comment: But you have to use method `SetValue` and `GetValue` to use dependency properties, not storing it in some private variable, like you did.

Comment: It's not being stored in a private variable - line 134 shows that

Comment: Yes, command. But I was reffering to your `Text` and `Source` properties.